# How to update a UIPickerview after changing it's data source contents

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I have 2 UIPickerViews in an ios program which I am running on an iPad simulator.
They have one component in each.
I find the relevant picker view by using a switch on the tag. The two single component views need to be changed by adding or deleting components.
This is easy enough in the data source with
`pickerData.append(textInput)`
`pickerData.sort()`
`pickerData.reloadAllComponents`
and
`pickerData.remove(at: lastDataSelected)`
`picker.reloadAllComponents()`
where lastDataSelected is the row integer.

This works to change the data source but not entirely when transferred to the UIPickerViews. 
The UIPickerView display is not updated until I scroll the view. To be more precise, the item selected is correct but the text label is not updated. After scrolling the data labels are all showing correctly.
I have tried to programatically scroll from one end to the other but this does not help.

So how can I tell the program to update the view without the user scrolling it? 
picker.reloadInputViews() does not help.

Apart from this the number of items (rows) isn't changed to reflect the changes in the picker data so the last item falls off the list when adding a new one.
So the second question is how to get the UIPickerView functions to update the number of rows?

I haven't been able to find any examples of dynamically updated picker views so hope someone can help or point me in the right direction.
The remaining code is fairly standard I believe but I'm obviously missing something in the update process.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    flvPicker = UIPickerView()
    flvPicker.delegate = self
    flvPicker.dataSource = self
    flvPicker.tag = 0
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    switch pickerView.tag {
    case 0:
        return 1
    case 1:
        etc...
    }
}
var numberOfRowsInComponent = 0
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    switch pickerView.tag {
    case 0:
        return flvPickerData.count
    case 1:
        etc...
    }
}
func pickerView(_
    pickerView: UIPickerView,
                titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch pickerView.tag {
    case 0:
        return flvPickerData[row]
    case 1:
        etc...
    }
}


func pickerView( _ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    switch pickerView.tag {
    case 0:
        flavourSelected = flvPickerData[row]
        lastFlavourSelected = row
    case 1: etc...
    }
}
```

I think the question is really how to get the UIPickerView to update correctly after making changes to it's data source and therefore row count.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reloadComponent(_:)` method from `UIPickerView`.

Comment: That does not work but then neither does flvPicker.reloadAllComponents(). The list is updated as before and it is visible after scrolling but the number of rows remains the same so the last item rolls off the list when adding an item.

Comment: While tinkering around with this I came across " 'row' is a 'let' constant, ie not mutable so it cannot be updated to a new number of rows.

Comment: This being part of the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol is there any way to workaround this? Would there be some way to reinitialise the picker view?

Comment: It should be fine just calling `reloadComponent(_:)` or `reloadAllComponents()`. Also, make sure that you're calling that on the main thread. (`DispatchQueue.main.async { }`).

Comment: DispatchQueue... ?

Comment: Oops, another premature 'return'. I cannot see or find that anywhere. Did you see the 'swift' and 'ios' tags?

Comment: Yeah, `reloadAllComponents()` should work. Using `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.flvPicker.reloadAllComponents() }` will ensure that's running on the main thread and it will immediately display the updates.

Comment: I see, I have to add that command. How do I do the function declaration and anywhere in the code or in 'viewDidLoad'?

Comment: My bad. I don't seem to need to declare that as a function at all. If I add this to my 'add to list' routine it still doesn't update until I touch/move the UIPickerView one arm bandit. Ditto if I put the command in the 'didSelectRow'. I'm checking this by using a 'pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)' with the UIPicker set halfway down the list.

Comment: After more testing it seems the only way to have a UIPickerView update immediately is to send the dispatch within the UIPickerView routines eg in the didSelectRow routine. Any dispatch from outside those routines, eg from my 'addToList' routine, is not executed immediately but works after touching the UIPickerView. This might not be the way it is supposed to work but it is doing so. A workaround - have the 'addToList' as an item in the UIPickerView (didSelectRow) with suitable conditions which would ensure that it will update and re-scroll to item 0 automatically when 'addToList' is selected.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but if you want to update a picker view, there's also the method `selectRow`. This also has the benefit of an animation property, so you can animate any updates.

Example:

```
for (index, day) in weeklyOptions[0].enumerated() {
    if scheduledTime.contains(day) {
        weeklyDatePicker.selectRow(index, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: But how does this update (ie. add, change, or delete items) the picker's data, like the question asks?

Comment: @DougNull, You're right. I misread the question. I was thinking of updating the position, not the data.

Comment: @DougNull, You're right. I misread the question. I was thinking of updating the position, not the data.